# IDEA (Java): how to see all classes which inherits from this one

Tags: java, intellij-idea

If I have some abstract (or not, doesn't matter) class - can I find all classes which inherits from this class?

Comment: It's called Type Hierarchy, I don't know where the command is in IntelliJ but in Eclipse you can right click any class/interface and click Open Type Hierarchy

Comment: If you're ever stuck without an IDE, a search across your project for `" extends YourClassName"` will help you find subclasses (though you'll need to re-search for sub-subclasses etc.

Comment: @Kon, I found it already. In IDEA it's: Navigate -> type hierarchy (Ctrl+H or alt+8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Kon pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311855/idea-java-how-to-see-all-classes-which-inherits-from-this-one#comment44974284_28311855), this is called Type Hierarchy. To find this in IntelliJ, either use the <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> shortcut, or go to Navigate and Type Hierarchy.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on your key binding but from what I remember by default in Idea it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (or the equivalent of ctrl on your platform).

If that's not the case then **the** shortcut you should know is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> which allows you to find actions (and lists them with their keybinds) based on a random query!